# (node:11536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got these errors on the code and I don't know what to do. Somebody I asked said

> "Set business of alhambra `hasEntrance = false`"

but i dont understand at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code required to understand your question should be pasted into your question as text and formatted appropriately.  It should not be in images.  Please fix your question.  There are a number of reasons for it (inlcude site policies), but the ones that will help you the most is it allows people to immediately see the code and it allows people who want to write answers to copy portions of your code into their answer rather than having to retype everything from scratch.  You will get more answers if you make it easy for people to see and understand your question and write an answer.

Comment: It appears that in `x: bizz.entrance.x` `bizz.entrance` is `null`, but `bizz.haveEntrance` is `true`.  You will have to look at your own code to figure out why that is.  I'm confused why you can't just look at the stack trace and see where the error is occurring and then debug the problem yourself.  This is very basic level debugging which you should not be coming here for.  You can use `console.log()` statements or trace through the function in the debugger and see exactly what is going on.